# React Native - No safe area insets value available

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> No safe area insets value available. Make sure you are rendering <SafeAreaProvider> at the top of your app

I wrapped my whole app in it and i still get the error

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import Main from './Main';
import store from './src/redux/store';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

export default function App() {

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StatusBar style='auto' hidden />
        <Main />
      </Provider>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `SafeAreaProvider` not `SafeAreaView`

```
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
```